# Unexplained different omp_get_wtime() for the same exact computation

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I am writing a code in Visual Studio (actually C++) and I realized that when running a particular function on parallel (just doing basic matrix multiplication), the computational times taken is very different with different runs in the same conditions.

have the following puzzling output:
1/ the first time I run the parallelized function, omg_get_wtime() gives a computational time way above the serial version
2/ the subsequent times I call it, it gives a much improved computational time.
my question is: how comes that same function gives different times in the first place (i.e. the first run gives a very different time than the subsequent runs...)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const int ROW = 50;
const int COL = 50; 

class matmul
{
    int a[ROW][COL];
    int row;
    int col;
    //int* prow;
public:
    matmul() : row(0), col(0) {} 
    ~matmul() {} 
    void display();
    matmul multiply_par1(matmul m1, matmul m2);


    void generate_matrix(int row, int col);
};



void matmul::display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            cout << setw(5) << a[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}




matmul matmul::multiply_par1(matmul m1, matmul m2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    matmul temp;
    temp.row = m1.row;
    temp.col = m2.col;
    double st = omp_get_wtime();
    int nbr = m1.row;
    int nbc = m2.col;

#pragma omp parallel private( i, j, k) // shared(nbr,nbc)
    for (i = 0; i < nbr; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < nbc; j++)
        {
            temp.a[i][j] = 0;
            {
                for (k = 0; k < temp.col; k++)
               temp.a[i][j] += m1.a[i][k] * m2.a[k][j];
            }
        }
    double en = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Parallel run: %lf\n", en - st);
    return temp;
}



void matmul::generate_matrix(int r, int c)
{
    //matrix temp;
    row = r;
    col = c;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }

}


int main()
{
    int Size = 10;
    int* arr = new int[Size];
    matmul m1, m2, m3, m4, m5,m6,m7;
    int r1, c1;

    if (Size > 100)
    {
        cout << "matrix quite large to display...\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Generating 1rst matrix...\n";
        m1.generate_matrix(10, 10);
        m1.display();
        cout << "Generating 2nd matrix...\n";
        m2.generate_matrix(10, 10);
        m2.display();



        m4 = m3.multiply_par1(m1, m2);
        cout << "Resultant parallel matrix is :\n";
        //m5.display();

        m5 = m3.multiply_par1(m1, m2);
        cout << "Resultant parallel matrix is :\n";
        //m6.display();


        m6 = m3.multiply_par1(m1, m2);
        cout << "Resultant parallel matrix is :\n";
        //m6.display();

        m7 = m3.multiply_par1(m1, m2);
        cout << "Resultant parallel matrix is :\n";
        //m6.display();



    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the running time to be bradly the same, but the first one is significantly different. I get the following output at execution:

```
Parallel running time: 0.000583
Resultant parallel matrix is :
Parallel running time: 0.000016
Resultant parallel matrix is :
Parallel running time: 0.000014
Resultant parallel matrix is :
Parallel running time: 0.000014
Resultant parallel matrix is :
```

As you see the 0.000583 really doesn't fit, and I don't see why...

**Crucially, in a situation where the piece of code above would be used once (say for a 500x500 matrix), is there an improvement we could perform on the code that could yield a better wtime()?**

Comment: It looks like the overhead to create the threads the first time. After that, it uses pooling so it becomes faster. Take a look at [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-obstacles-for-threading-how-do-they-affect-openmp-code) at "Thread startup overhead".

Comment: Sorry Gilles-Philippe I'm not an expert in openMP what do you mean by "overhead"? (I don't know what it is) [thanks also for your comment btw]

Comment: An [overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computing)) is an extra computation needed to perform a task. In your case, before performing the loop, OpenMP has to create threads, which takes time. If the matrix is very small, creating threads might cost more than the actual computation if it was done in a single thread. However, it may still be beneficial to use multi-threading if OpenMP can use [thread pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/thread-pools) in subsequent multi-threaded section.

Answer (score 4):

OpenMP has to create threads before executing the parallel section ([details](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-obstacles-for-threading-how-do-they-affect-openmp-code)). Creating threads takes time and this is what you are observing in your first measurement.

However, OpenMP implementations do not create new threads between parallel regions because it uses thread pooling (it recycles previously created threads). This is why the subsequent measurements are much better.

In your case, the matrices are quite small so the advantages of multi-threading are shadowed by the overhead of thread creation. For subsequent calls, it may however still be beneficial to use multi-threading. For this reason, always measure the first, the subsequent, and the total average to ensure that the piece of code is worth parallelizing in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Gilles-Philippe for the explanation. Crucially, in a situation where the piece of code above would be used once (say for a 500x500 matrix), is there an improvement we could perform on the code that could yield a better wtime()? [I might move this to the main question]

Comment: @Faissal If your application starts, do the matrix multiplication of the 500x500 matrix, and closes, then you have to measure to be sure that parallelizing if beneficial. If you mean that the code is called once in a while, then it might still be beneficial. In all case, the rule is to measure before making any conclusion.

Comment: pedantic point, the OpenMP standard does not require thread pools or that threads are not recreated between parallel sections. Your statement "OpenMP will not create new threads everytime it enters a parallel section" more accurately would state something like "OpenMP implementations do not create new threads between parallel regions". That's a statement that seems to be true in practice.

Comment: @Zboson Thanks for the correction, I will edit my answer following your recommendation.